# How to set the GaussianBlurEffect's object source to bitmap image

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, win2d

I'm using Win2D and i want to make a blur effect to an image, however i can't set the source of the blur effect to an image.

```
GaussianBlurEffect blur = new GaussianBlurEffect();
blur.Source = // cants accept a bitmap image 
blur.BlurAmount = 10.0f;
args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(blur);
```

Comment: [GaussianBlurEffect.Source Property](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/P_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Effects_GaussianBlurEffect_Source.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the doc provided by @IInspectable, the source of `GaussianBlurEffect` should be `ICanvasImage` type instead of a `BitmapImage`.

There are several methods to load a CanvasImage, for example directly load from a file:

```
var image = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, "Assets/miao4.jpg");
GaussianBlurEffect blur = new GaussianBlurEffect();
blur.Source = image;
blur.BlurAmount = 10.0f;
args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(blur, 400, 200);
```

For other methods, you can refer to [CanvasBitmap Class](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasBitmap.htm).